# Enter an Age value and count the number of rows of Name which match the entered Age

Tags: c#, .net

I want to search in a database table for the number of rows of Name. Let's say I enter the Age of 12, the compiler can search the Names which matches the Age of 12, and count the total rows of Name, how can I type the code? I'm using Linq DataRow[] but my code doesn't work. Here's my code, can any1 help me to fix the code?

```
DataRow[] setSTD = 
    db1.Tables["table1"].
        Select("Age =" + age).
        Select(n => n["Name"]);
```

Comment: @Mr Lister, `DataRow[]` does not support 2 `Select`, IEnumerable can use 2 `Select`, but I can't count the rows.
@AdrianIftode, sorry for that, still fresh learner of C#, but try my best now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### LINQ

```
var rows = db1.Tables["table1"]
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Where( o => o.Field<int>( "Age" ) == age );
```

This will return an enumerable collection of rows (from which you can extract the name column if desired) by adding `.Select( o => o.Field<string>( "Name" ) );`

If you need to count the rows, you can add `.Count()` to the end of any enumerable collection.

### TSQL

I would recommend doing this at the database level to avoid returning rows that you don't need, where the query would simply be:

```
DECLARE @Age INT = 12;
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Age = @Age;
```

### Non-LINQ .NET

There is a `Select()` method on `DataTable` which predates LINQ. LINQ is usually far superior, but for reference `Select()` can be passed a string filter such as "Age=12". `Select()` returns an array of DataRows.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx

Comment: If my `Name` is then changed into `DateTime` property, `<string>` needs to be changed?

Comment: Yes. `Field<>` is generic and takes the type of the column, like `Field<DateTime>`, `Field<string>`, `Field<int>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow[]setSTD = 
db1.Tables["table1"].Where(n => n["Age"] == age).Select(n => n["Name"]);
```

Comment: are u sure ur code works? I've tried ur method before, l cannot put `.Where` behind the `["table1"]`, it prompts out error....

Answer (score 0):

The following might work, but I have not tested this in a real environment:

```
string[] names = (from r in db1.Tables["table1"] where r["Age"] == age select r["Name"]);
```

The thing is: There's a `SELECT` in `DataTable` and there's the LINQ `Select`. You need to make sure not to mix them up.

Comment: Thx for ur info. Although l'm not using this now, but it can be used as future reference too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var age=12;
var results = from myRow in db1.Tables["table1"].AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field<int>("Age") == age
select myRow.Field<string>("Name");
```